# How to calculate excess-256 and excess-128?

Tags: binary

I have the number -37 in decimal. Could you please tell me what its representation is in excess-256 and excess-128?

Its normal binary representation is -100101 and in 8 bits 1010 0101. How exactly do I then get the excess-N representation for it? Am I allowed to have a number larger than 8 bits when writing excess-N? Would I thus have:

01010 0000 (first digit) + 10000 0000 and 00101 + 10000 00000?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to get it into excess 128, add the true value (-37) to 128. = 91, then get the binary value for 91, 1011011. Same applies for 256 i think.